# Python - Salesforce: How to find an object with no definitive class name and verify the text?

Tags: python, selenium, salesforce

So, currently I'm using Python 3 and the selenium webdriver with Salesforce to automate admin verifications.

I've been pretty successful (even though I'm not that proficient with programming). However, I've run into an issue... I can't seem to figure out how to find an element on the page so that I can verify the text contained within is accurately being displayed.

> This is what it looks like on the user's end:
>   [The highlighted element displays as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYaB2.png)

But whenever I search for "GlobalHeaderCommunitySwitcher", it spits back an error that it can't find it.

So I try searching for the other elements in the block of code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="zen-trigger" aria-haspopup="true" id="globalHeaderCommunitySwitcher" title="Press space bar or Enter key to open" data-uidsfdc="51"><b class="zen-selectArrow"></b>PVT GBI Internal</a>
<b class="zen-selectArrow"></b>
"PVT GBI Internal"
```

I've come up empty each time by searching by:

> browser.find_element_by_id("globalHeaderCommunitySwitcher")
>      browser.find_element_by_class_name & used "zen-trigger" and "zen-selectArrow"
>      browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='zen-trigger'and text()='PVT GBI Internal']")

This also results in nothing being returned..

**Essentially, how do I locate the element in the screenshot via the above code and then have the script verify that the text within that element ("PVT GBI INTERNAL") is present and correct?**

Comment: Are you sure the element exists at the time you try to find it? It may need a bit of time to show up, what if you set an implicit wait?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So my code currently includes an implicit wait of 10 seconds. I've also considered that this may have to do with the focus of the tabs, however I've verified that the focus is on the correct webpage.

Comment: If you `print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML'))` can you see the element in the output?

Comment: @SalIaniero - if it does not require credentials, then can you share the url with us ?

Comment: try this:  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='zen-trigger']//*[text()='PVT GBI Internal']")

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the page using the google chrome browser
2. Move the mouse over the element that you want to find and right-click it
3. Left click Inspect (at the bottom of the selection list)
4. Your element will be hi-lighted in the Developers tools
5. Right click the hi-lighted element and select Copy
6. Click either copy Selector or XPath depending on your preference
7. Paste that into your selenium find_element_by_xpath() or find_element_by_css_selector() statement as appropriate.

Say xpath

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("your pasted xpath")
assert element.text == 'Your expected text'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `//tag[text()="value"] or //tag[contains(attribute,‘value’)]`

example : `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='zen-trigger']//*[‌​text()='PVT GBI Internal']")`

```
//a[@class='zen-trigger']//*[contains(text(),'PVT GBI Internal')]
//a[@class='zen-trigger']//*[contains(@class="zen-selectArrow")and
contains(text(),'PVT GBI Internal')]
```